# What is the meaning of the default intent filter for the MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

When a new app is created in android, the sdk creates a default intent filter for you MainActivity as shown below. Can anyone explain the significance of this intent-filter. Who is using this MAIN action?

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />                
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />                
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, Android OS is the one who uses and deciphers those constants and knows exactly what to do with your app.

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

Means that this `Activity` is the main entry point to your application. It is the first thing that will be called when you application starts.

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Means that this `Activity` is a launching activity for your application (it starts the application) so an icon will be placed on your phone to be able to launch it.

Technically you can have more than one activity with these attributes and each of them would have an icon and be the first thing that is called when you click this icon. However, this is not really practical to do.

You should [visit this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) for all about `Intents`

Also, now that you have an idea what these constants mean, play around with them, create some activities and try out combinations to see what happens. Best way to understand things is to try them out yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

This intent is used to instruct that the launcher (the home screen app) should present all top-level activity objects as icons available for selection.  This is basically the glue that tells the Launcher that this APK has an application it would like to be launched from it.  Therefore the launcher then creates and manages an icon that will dispatch to this app.

`android.intent.action.MAIN` matches all top-level entry points
 `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` tells the launcher these should appear as icons